# Add class name for anchor Params in Magento2 via XML

Tags: layout, magento2

My memories in M1x, From xml use aParams tag can add class name for anchor. But in M2 seem this tag have removed. Where can i find this params in code
Anyone have experience on this case

---

@Marius top links from M1 i can use xml to add class name to anchor

xml you can see below link
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wWLmXEnW 

I want to do that in M2 but seem this way not work. Any idea on this case

What class name will render top links in M2?

Many thanks

Comment: can you provide an example of what you did in M1 and what do you expect on M2? your question is not really clear.

Comment: @marius take a notice

Answer (score 1):

If you need add class to top.links block use layouts like

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
  <arguments>
       <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">my-class</argument>
  </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

if you need add new link to top.links use layout like

```
    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="top-link-myaccount">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My Account</argument>
                <argument name="href" xsi:type="url">customer/getAccountUrl</argument>
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">top-link-myaccount</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: i have tried this way but getting DOM error

Comment: can  you show the layout file

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/btsxnab71kfwnaf/Screenshot%202015-10-02%2023.30.27.png

Comment: This way, the A element will get a Class. How can I modify this XML in order to give its li parent element a class?

Comment: For some reason <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">my-class</argument> does not take effect for anchor elements on M2.1.x